# Expand View Animation - Issue

Tags: android, animation

I'm new to android in my application i expand my view my following set of code animation:

```
Animation expansion = createExpansion(mytextview);
                    expansion.setDuration(400);
                    mytextview.startAnimation(expansion);
```

following set of function:

```
public static Animation createExpansion(View view) {

            return new SizedHeightScaleAnimation(view, 0, 1,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
        }
```

And this is my SizedHeightScaleAnimation.class file:

```
public class SizedHeightScaleAnimation extends ScaleAnimation{


    private float fromHeight;
    private float toHeight;
    private View viewToScale;

    public SizedHeightScaleAnimation(View viewToScale, float fromY, float toY) {
        super(1, 1, fromY, toY);
        init(viewToScale, fromY, toY);
    }

    public SizedHeightScaleAnimation(View viewToScale, float fromY, float toY, float pivotX, float pivotY) {
        super(1, 1, fromY, toY, pivotX, pivotY);
        init(viewToScale, fromY, toY);
    }

    public SizedHeightScaleAnimation(View viewToScale, float fromY, float toY, int pivotXType, float pivotXValue, int pivotYType, float pivotYValue) {
        super(1, 1, fromY, toY, pivotXType, pivotXValue, pivotYType, pivotYValue);
        init(viewToScale, fromY, toY);
    }

    private void init(View viewToScale, float fromY, float toY) {

        this.viewToScale = viewToScale;
        viewToScale.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        fromHeight = viewToScale.getMeasuredHeight() * fromY;
        toHeight = viewToScale.getMeasuredHeight() * toY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

        final int newHeight = (int) (fromHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime) + toHeight * interpolatedTime );


        viewToScale.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
        viewToScale.requestLayout();
    }
```

And the view gets expand but some of last line's in that discription is not visible it's cuts some portion of that discription.can anyone please help what went wrong/any mistake in calculation,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
new SizedHeightScaleAnimation(view, 0, 1,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
```

is equivalent to:

```
new ScaleAnimation(1, 1, 0, 1,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
```

You are just scaling the view from height(0) to its original height. So the description is too long for the textview compared to its height set on the view. That's why its getting cut. There is no issue with the scaling.

Comment: Yes i agree,but if make changes like this new SizedHeightScaleAnimation(view, 0, 1.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f); the larger discription wil not get cut but for smaller discription underneath there is an space

Comment: And if i make changes in SizedHeightScaleAnimation.class calculation like final int newHeight = (int) (fromHeight * /*(1 - interpolatedTime)*/ + toHeight * interpolatedTime ); the discription wil not cut but smooth animation part is missing :(

Answer (score 0):

i tried another way  of method to solve my problem and it's worked for me only thing is I couldn't able to make an smooth transition by setting animation duration for it.below is the solution for that description cut problem:

```
private void expand(View summary) {
            //set Visible
            summary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                   summary.measure(widthSpec, 0);
                    //summary.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                    mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, 0, summary);

            mAnimator.start();
            //mAnimator.setDuration(700);

        }


        private ValueAnimator slideAnimator(int start, int end, final View summary) {

            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);
            //animator.setDuration(700);

            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    //Update Height
                    int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = summary.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = value;
                   //layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    summary.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                }
            });
            return animator;
        }
```

Comment: Can anyone tell how to set duration for above code please